# Reading and Writing a JSON file with Exact formate

Tags: java, json

I am working with a json file's sha:256 value. I have a json file, i need to read it and remove one specific element from the json value and write it back to the file. But the thing is i can't remove the formatting the file have, not even a whitespace, only the exact element. 1 white space removal cause different hash value. So i cant remove anything rather than the element. For an  example :

JSON file:

```
{
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "ball",
    "c": "cat"
}
```

Then removing one element my file need to look like this:

```
{
    "a": "apple",
    "c": "cat"
}
```

How can I do this using Java?

Comment: You mean to say that the indentation should remain the same as you get in JSON file?

Comment: If you don't remove any whitespace, then shouldn't your output file have a line with four spaces in between `"a": "apple",` and `"c": "cat"`?

Comment: @immibis There is exact same space between those in given file and output file.

Comment: @Sadlil I mean, why are you allowed to remove the whitespace before the entry?

Comment: @immibis i am not allowed to remove any thing except the desire eement. Cause a single whitespace removing cause massive change at its sha value. On the example i didn't remove whitespces. It looks same on my screen.

Comment: @Sadlil Your input contains 15 spaces and 4 newlines. Your output contains 10 spaces and 3 newlines. Therefore you removed 5 spaces and 1 newline.

Comment: yeah its because i remove an element and so the spaces and newline with that element that needs to remove to for prettyfying. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can deserialize json to a `Map` and remove key which you want to remove. After you serialize that `Map` to json and write it to the file. Example I use `Gson` for serialize and deserialize:

Deserialize:

```
String json = "{'a': 'apple', 'b': 'ball', 'c': 'cat'}";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Serialize:

```
gson.toJson(myMap)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have use jackson. And there is some PrettyPrinter methods that could formate the json as i wanted..

My Code:

```
  DefaultPrettyPrinter prettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
  prettyPrinter.indentArraysWith(new DefaultIndenter("   ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF));
  prettyPrinter.indentObjectsWith(new DefaultIndenter("   ", DefaultIndenter.SYS_LF));
  String ret = mapper.writer(prettyPrinter).writeValueAsString(json);
```